# Apache mod_rewrite appending index.html to the request

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, routes, url-routing

In my .htaccess I have the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I access my application like this: http://myapp/
A dump of the $_REQUEST array shows

```
Array ( [_url] => /index.html )
```

Why? Where does this index.html come from? How can I get rid of it?

**UPDATE:**

I actually have another .htaccess before, here is the complete picture

at the root of the application I have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and then inside the public folder I have the htaccess that I previously mentioned.

Comment: I think it probably has something to do with the default DirectoryIndex  directive of mod_dir: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: If it's a `DirectoryIndex` issue, you can use `DirectoryIndex disabled` since Apache 2.4. Anyway, is this your entire htaccess code ? Do you have other htaccess files ? Are you using a framework (Wordpress, etc) ?

Comment: When I use DirectoryIndex disabled I get the Forbidden error. Yeah, I'm using a PHP framework, but the issue arises even before the framework has the chance to analyse the request. I updated the question with the other .htaccess I have.

Comment: Try using `DirectoryIndex index.php` instead.

Comment: `DirectoryIndex index.php` did the trick, but not sure if it's the right solution because the request variable `_url` just disappears. Any thoughts?

Comment: 'DirectoryIndex /' could help